# ASP.NET MVC: putting custom attributes into option tag in select list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, and am trying to render a select list with the HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor method, like so:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AllTopics, SelectListHelper.GetSelectListItems(Model.AllTopics), "Select a Topic", new { id = "allTopics", @class = "topic-dropdown" })%>
```

where SelectListHelper just returns an `IList<SelectListItem>` from whatever collection we're passing in. This works fine for simple things, but I want to be able to add a title attribute to each **option** tag (**not** the **select** list itself). But the DropDownListFor only takes in an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, and the SelectListItem does not have anyplace that I can put in the title attribute.

Is there any way to do this without foregoing the DropDownListFor method and writing out the select list and each element by hand?

Answer (score 4):

DropDownList and derivatives don't support the functionality you're looking for. But you could also simply process the string returned by DropDownList.

```
<%= 
  Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AllTopics,
    SelectListHelper.GetSelectListItems(Model.AllTopics),
    "Select a Topic", 
    new { id = "allTopics", @class = "topic-dropdown" })
  .Replace("<option", "<option attr=\"value\"")
%>
```

Comment: This **would** be the easiest, but the problem arises when I need a different value for the title attribute for every option. Then it becomes a nightmare of string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the MVC source code, `DropDownListFor` uses `DropDownList`, which uses `SelectInternal`, which uses `ListItemToOption`, which wraps calls to TagBuilder. You could modify and include this source to accept extra calls to TagBuilder when the actual option tag is built.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing... basically ripping out a bunch of code from .NET Reflector. Seems to work, but makes me kinda nervous because of all the other crap these methods seem to be doing, which can get kinda hard to decipher. I guess we'll just fix it as it goes.

Comment: No need to use Reflector; the code for ASP.NET MVC is publicly available: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471