# HTML 5 dropdown in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to render this

```
<select>
  <option data_x="1">Volvo</option>
  <option data_x="2">Saab</option>
  <option data_x="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option data_x="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can i use Html.DropDownListFor

```
[for example:@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedPlanCodeID, new SelectList(Model.PlanCodeList, "ID", "Plancode"), " Select ")]
```

to render this?

Answer (score 0):

`DropDownListFor` doesn't support it natively, you can either do a find/replace on the result of `DropDownListFor` or you can write your own HTML helper to do it.  See this similar question:

[ASP.NET MVC: putting custom attributes into option tag in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829566/asp-net-mvc-putting-custom-attributes-into-option-tag-in-select-list)